# Deploy Asp.Net ABP angular and asp.net core with Docker Compose to Azure

Tags: docker-compose, azure-web-app-service, aspnetboilerplate, abp

I have a project with Asp.Net ABP angular and asp.net core.

With Docker, it will build with docker like below:

[image]

I am wondering how to deploy them to Azure Docker Compose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this [quick start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-multi-container) guide. You can create a web app by using following CLI command

```sh
az webapp create --resource-group myResourceGroup --plan myAppServicePlan --name <app_name> --multicontainer-config-type compose --multicontainer-config-file docker-compose.yml
```

If you use the portal, [create](https://portal.azure.com/#create/Microsoft.AppSvcLinux) a Web App for Containers app service specifying your container registry and upload your docker-compose.yml file.

[image: create-azure-web-app-for-containers]

Comment: For `docker-compose.yml`, it will need docker image. For local computer, I could build it with docker, and then use with `docker-compose`, how could Azure access my local image when use your command?

Comment: @Edward you have to push your images to a registry. You can either push your docker images to your own repo in docker hub or [create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-get-started-azure-cli#create-a-container-registry) a container registry in Azure and push your images there. You can then select the source registry and enter the image tag as shown the screenshot. Configuration File is your `docker-compose.yml`.